# ggplot 0.9.3 issue with facet_wrap, free scales and coord_flip

Tags: r, ggplot2

This simple code from a sample demo does not work anymore in 0.9.3.

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- qplot(displ, hwy, data = mpg)
p + facet_wrap(~ cyl, scales = "free_y") + coord_flip()
```

The above code now produces the error:

```
Error in facet_render.wrap(plot$facet, panel, plot$coordinates, plot_theme(plot),  : 
  ggplot2 does not currently support free scales with a non-cartesian coord or coord_flip.
```

What are some workarounds to get something similar. Thanks!

====================================================== 2nd try

Finally came around to creating a small example. Here is a way to reproduce:

data set: d.csv:

```
"Priority","Owner","Project"
"Medium","owner7","Team4"
"Medium","owner1","Team1"
"Low","","Team3"
"High","owner6","Team3"
"Medium","","Team4"
"Medium","owner3","Team1"
"Medium","owner2","Team1"
"Medium","owner5","Team2"
"Low","owner4","Team2"
"Critical","","Team2"
"Medium","owner2","Team1"
"High","","Team4"
```

Code:

```
data <- read.csv(file="d.csv",head=TRUE)
attach(data)

p3 <- ggplot(data,aes(x=Owner,fill=Priority))+
geom_bar(aes(y=..count..)) + 
facet_wrap(~ Project, nrow=2, scales="free") +
opts(legend.position="none")
```

This creates a faceted plot but I need the axes flipped. Previously, adding a coord_flip() did the trick but now the new ggplot does not permit using free scales and coord_flip together. Is there any other way to turn the facet axes around? The free scales are important to me. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Well, use fixed scales, e.g., `p + facet_wrap(~ cyl) + coord_flip()` or avoid `coord_flip` ...

Comment: Why not reverse displ and hwy to avoid using coord_flip?

Comment: My actual issue was with bar charts and there there seems to be no way to get horizontal bars (no geom_hbar) besides using coord_flip(). Fixed scales and facets don't always go together well depending on data. Let me see if I can provide a useful code sample. Thanks.

Comment: Prior to 0.9.3 using facets with a free x scale along with a coord_flip was a great way to generate bar charts (notably without empty rows). That's likely why the free scales + coord_flip is important to this question. Suggestions to avoid either won't really help @Prasad.